Power Bi Web Data Refresh
I came across the below problem while setting up the schedule refresh on power Bi web. any help/solution will be appreciate.
Data source errorExpression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.. Key = [Name = "dubaiproperties"]. Table = #table({"Name", "Description", "Data", "Kind", "DisplayName"}, {}). ;The key didn't match any rows in the table.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: DP_SUMMARY.
I tried reconnecting the data source. when I refresh the data in desktop version it works, but whenever I try refreshing the data in the power bi workspace it throws an error
